# Loop for applying mask and creating a vector of means

Tags: r, loops

I want to create a vector of means after applying a mask to a number of text files (1,408). Each file corresponding to a variable & year from 1950-2013, so 64 files for that variable and there are 22 variables. this is the coding I applied in R:

```
dataDir <- "C:\\dir\\"
patternC <-"Var1_"
filesSizeC = sort(list.files(dataDir,patternC))

  for (i in 1:length(filesSizeC)) {
   theData<-read.table(paste(dataDir,filesSizeC[i],sep=""),header=F,sep=",")
}

mask <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/2tbffe65i53afj1/examplemask.txt",
header=F)

product <- mask * theData
product[product == 0] <- NA
mean(product$V1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

This only gives me one value, the mean, for the 64 text files. But I want the mean for each text file after the masking has been applied. I amended the coding to this, to try and give me a vector of means for each year:

```
for (i in 1:length(filesSizeC)) {
theData<-read.table(paste(dataDir,filesSizeC[i],sep=""),header=F,sep="\t")  
pdt <- mask*theData

if (i>0) {
    theMeanValues <- c(theMeanValues,mean(pdt))

  } else {
  theMeanValues <- c(mean(pdt))
 }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error: object 'theMeanValues' not found
```

I'm not too sure how to change this for what I want.

So essentially I want to achieve this:

```
year | Var1_Masked_Mean | Var2_Masked_Mean | etc...
1950
1951
 .
 .
 .
2013
```

I hope what I'm asking makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible example datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is indexed at `1` not `0` in your example...

```
for (i in 1:length(filesSizeC)) {
```

So change this

```
if (i>0) {
  ...
  }
```

to

```
if (i>1) {
  ...
  }
```

And in the first iteration of the loop when `i==1` you will create the `theMeanValues` variable.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I return `theMeanValues` it returns 64 NA's, how do I get values for these instead?

Comment: @hgeop did you remember to put `mean( pdt , na.rm = TRUE )`?!

Comment: Sorry, I needed to put mean(pdt$V1, na.rm=T), it's now working. Thanks for your help @SimonO101

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `theMeanValues` with something like:

```
theMeanValues <- vector(length=length(filesSizeC))
```

And then you can store your results `mean(pdt)` of each iteration into a position in that vector with:

```
theMeanValues[i] <- mean(pdt)
```

This will prevent the error and be more efficient than growing your `theMeanValues` vector with `c()` each iteration.

But, it also sounds like you may want to initialize a matrix and extract a vector from each iteration of your `for`-loop...but it's not really clear from your question.